# How to make web-mode read mjs-files in Emacs

Tags: list, emacs

I'm trying to get web-mode to read mjs-files as jsx or js files. I did this by adding

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.mjs\\'" . web-mode))
```

The problem is when I eval `web-mode-content-type`, I get `html`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Your question seems to be about `web-mode`, and has nothing to do with `auto-mode-alist`. Presumably you have the same problem if you visit a `*.mjs` file and then turn on `web-mode`.

Comment: @drew Yes, indeed I have. web-mode is for some reason unable to identify the content type when opening a mjs-file.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're looking for `'web-mode-content-types-alist`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by adding the following to my init file.

```lisp
(setq web-mode-content-types-alist
      '(("jsx" . "\\.[c|m]js[x]?\\'")))
```